# How can I save my shoppers' credit cards in Bluesnap?

Tags: bluesnap

I'm integrating bluesnap's payment API with my website. How do I store the card information in bluesnap so that I don't have to do it in my own database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Payment API, you can save credit card data at the shopper level. To do this, you create a saved shopper in BlueSnap and include the card data for that shopper. You can also include information like the shopper's name and address.

For example:

```
<vaulted-shopper xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
   <first-name>FirstName</first-name>
   <last-name>LastName</last-name>
   <payment-sources>
      <credit-card-info>
         <credit-card>
            <card-number>4263982640269299</card-number>
            <security-code>837</security-code>
            <expiration-month>02</expiration-month>
            <expiration-year>2018</expiration-year>
         </credit-card>
         <billing-contact-info>
            <first-name>billingFirstName</first-name>
            <last-name>billingLastName</last-name>
            <country>US</country>
            <state>MA</state>
            <address1>10 Main St</address1>
            <address2>Apt 1</address2>
            <email>email@example.com</email>
            <zip>01752</zip>
         </billing-contact-info>
      </credit-card-info>
   </payment-sources>
</vaulted-shopper>
```

More information and examples are here: http://developers.bluesnap.com/v2.0/docs/create-vaulted-shopper

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it on my sandbox account and it's working as expected.